# How can I assure a pure virtual method is called from my derived class?

Tags: c++

I have the following situation:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual void make_sure_im_called() = 0;
};

class Child : public Base {
  public:
    virtual void make_sure_im_called()
    {
      std::cout << "I was called as intended." << std::endl;
    };
}
```

It is so that I want every class that derives from Base to implement make_sure_im_called() (which is successfully done by making it pure virtual). But how can I assert that someone deriving a new class from Base is also forced to call the function? It seems that everything I try from the base class will fail because of the missing implementation.

Comment: You might want to add `override` to the method in Child

Comment: Depending on when it needs to be called, you might be able to call it from the base constructor

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but are you looking for the Non-Virtual Interface pattern?

Comment: Otherwise, you can look into making `make_sure_im_called` `final` and adding another `virtual` hook for further derived classes

Comment: @BruceFeldman is right, if you **need** that function to be called in order for a class to inherit from your Base, it should be part of the constructor (or extremely well documented)

Comment: Since you don't provide any implementation in the base class, what's the point of forcing the children classes to call this method? It's not like they are missing something by not calling it.

Comment: If it is pure virtual, how can it be called from the constructor? I'm first getting compiler warnings that i'm doing that and then it tells me the reference to Base::make_sure_im_called() is undefined.

Comment: your base class is called an abstract class because of the pure virtual function...it has to be inherited to be used...the pure virtual cannot be used because it is not complete...your question is unclear, please provide an example

Comment: The people here who are suggesting you call it in the constructor, seem to have forgotten that function calls in constructor are resolved statically, with no dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @SkuSku *When* do you need the function to be called? There may be other ways to achieve what you need. E.g. Builder Pattern, smart pointers, auxiliary base classes or members or constructor parameters. *Why* do you need it to be called? You force derived classes to call a function on themselves, which they can implement to be empty... I'm curious. :)

Comment: @PabloH When?: I want the derived class to call the method upon construction. Why?: I want them to "register themselves" in a static map that resides in the base class

Comment: @SkuSku Then, it depends on what is in involved in "registering", your set of classes, etc. E.g. you *might* get away with simply `register(this)` in the constructor of the base class; or maybe creating all derived clases through a single (templated) friend function that does the registering, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ there is no build-in construct which does what you want, though, you can always enforce it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    Base() = default;
    void make_sure_im_called() {
       before_make_sure_im_called();
       // Your own code
       after_make_sure_im_called();
    }
  protected:
    // Hooks to be implemented
    virtual void before_make_sure_im_called() = 0;
    virtual void after_make_sure_im_called() = 0;
};

class Child : public Base {
  protected:
    virtual void before_make_sure_im_called() override
    {
      std::cout << "I was called as intended." << std::endl;
    };
    virtual void after_make_sure_im_called() override {}
}
```

This results in 2 virtual calls (most of the time, you can survive with 1 of them).
If someone calls `make_sure_im_called`, this now will call the pure virtual calls.

By making them protected, the chance of them being called is reduced as only derived classes can access them.

### Enforcing this method being called in the lifespan of the instance.

The method `make_sure_im_called` can't be called from within the constructor of `Base`. There is no construction which can enforce this, though, you could let the program crash if this was not the case.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    Base() = default;
    ~Base() { assert(_initialized && "Some message"); }
    void make_sure_im_called() {
       before_make_sure_im_called();
       // Your own code
       after_make_sure_im_called();
       _initialized = true;
    }
  protected:
    // Hooks to be implemented
    virtual void before_make_sure_im_called() = 0;
    virtual void after_make_sure_im_called() = 0;

  private:
      bool _initialized{false};
};

class Child : public Base {
  protected:
    virtual void before_make_sure_im_called() override {};
    virtual void after_make_sure_im_called() override {}
}
```

By keeping the `_initialized` member, you can keep track of the method being called. In the Dtor, you can assert on this and crash the program if this is false (debug-builds only?). Exercise to the reader: get copy/move-construction/assignment right.

The solution might not be that elegant, though, at least it will be better than having nothing at all. One could even document this as part of the API.

Comment: Why not make them private?

Comment: @KerrekSB I assume it's so that further derived classes can call the parent's implementation if they just want to add extra behavior

Comment: I was doubting, though; there is no difference as the Child can make this public again. I also don't know if you want to have other derived classes still inheriting from this.

Comment: Calling make_sure_im_called() from the Base constructor will still not work, will it?

Comment: No, that won't work, as with any virtual function (unless in final classes)

Comment: This is effectively what was above called the "Non-virtual interface pattern", right?

Comment: Can be, haven't read the comments while typing, nor do I know that concept by name.

Comment: Yes, it is what I was refering to

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the strongest way this is going to work. Although I would have liked to call the functions from the constructor but that does not seem to be possible for logical reasons. Thanks everyone, I'll accept your answer.